# Adjust two controls vertically by their font baseline at runtime

Tags: delphi, fonts, delphi-10.3-rio, baseline

In my applications there are many cases when I have several groups of `TLabel` followed by a `TEdit` on my Forms, you know... when some properties needs to be edited. I want to align vertically those controls so that their font [baseline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)) will be on the same line. I need to do this at runtime, after I scale the Form and everything is messed up. Do yo know if there is a way to do that ? I saw that Delphi IDE does it verry easy at design time...

Edit: I managed to get the position of the baseline relative to font margins, with `GetTextMetrics` but now I don't know where the font Top is positioned in the control client area (TLabel and TEdit)...

Comment: Yes, as you say, at design time this is super easy: the *pink* guidelines make sure the baselines are aligned. Good question about how to best do this at runtime. I'd start by looking at the `TLabel` source code.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Regarding the `TEdit`... I found in the source code how the Height is calculated but I don't find anywhere the coordinates where the text si drawn... The `TCustomEdit` has no Paint method. I don't understand who draws it...

Comment: Marus: The `TEdit` is merely a wrapper for the operating systems' (=Microsoft Windows') [EDIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-controls) control. Hence, the `TEdit` VCL control merely asks Windows to create one of its EDIT controls. That's why the `TEdit` looks exactly like the edit boxes in other Win32 applications, but different from the (buggy) FMX edit control, for instance.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923936/equivalent-to-designer-guidelines-in-code

Comment: use panels and let delphi do the work for you :)

Comment: I'm thinking pretty seriously about making my own controls from scratch... I've been tormented all my life by these default controls from Delphi, which have all sorts of shortcomings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that aligns some common controls... I don't know if it covers all the cases, but what I've tried so far has worked perfectly. It works in current Windows versions but God knows what will happen in future versions, when they will change the way controls are drawn.

```
  TControlWithFont = class (TControl)
  public
    property Font;
  end;

procedure FontBaselineAlign(Control, FixedControl: TControl);
var DC: HDC;
    SaveFont: HFont;
    CtrlBL, FixBL, BV: Integer;
    CtrlTM, FixTM: TTextMetric;

 function GetControlBaseLine(Ctrl: Tcontrol; const TM: TTextMetric; out BL: Integer): Boolean;
 begin
  Result:= False; BL:= -1;

  if Ctrl is TLabel then with Ctrl as TLabel do begin
   if Layout = tlTop then BL:= TM.tmAscent
    else if Layout = tlBottom then BL:= Height - TM.tmDescent
     else BL:= ((Height - TM.tmHeight) div 2 + TM.tmAscent);
   Result:= True;
  end

  else if Ctrl is TEdit then with Ctrl as TEdit do begin
   BL:= TM.tmAscent;
   if BorderStyle = bsSingle then
   Inc(BL, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYEDGE)+1);
   Result:= True;
  end

  else if (Ctrl is TSpinEdit) or (Ctrl is TComboBox) then begin
   BL:= TM.tmAscent + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYEDGE)+1;
   Result:= True;
  end

  else if (Ctrl is TComboBoxEx) then begin
   BL:= TM.tmAscent + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYEDGE)+3;
   Result:= True;
  end

  else if (Ctrl is TCheckBox) or (Ctrl is TRadioButton) then begin
   BL:= ((Ctrl.Height - TM.tmHeight) div 2) + TM.tmAscent;
   Result:= True;
  end

  else if (Ctrl is TColorBox) then begin
   BL:= Round((Ctrl.Height - TM.tmHeight) / 2) + TM.tmAscent;
   Result:= True;
  end

  else if (Ctrl is TPanel) then with Ctrl as TPanel do begin
   BV:= BorderWidth;
   if BevelInner <> bvNone then Inc(BV, BevelWidth);
   if BevelOuter <> bvNone then Inc(BV, BevelWidth);
   if BorderStyle = bsSingle then Inc(BV, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYEDGE));
   if VerticalAlignment = taAlignTop then begin
    if (BevelKind <> bkNone) and (beTop in BevelEdges) then Inc(BV, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYEDGE));
    BL:= BV + TM.tmAscent;
   end
    else if VerticalAlignment = taAlignBottom then begin
     if (BevelKind <> bkNone) and (beBottom in BevelEdges) then Inc(BV, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYEDGE));
     BL:= Height - TM.tmDescent - BV;
    end
     else BL:= ((Height - TM.tmHeight) div 2 + TM.tmAscent);
   Result:= True;
  end;
 end;

begin
 DC:= GetDC(0);
 try
  SaveFont:= SelectObject(DC, TControlWithFont(Control).Font.Handle);
  GetTextMetrics(DC, CtrlTM);
  SelectObject(DC, TControlWithFont(FixedControl).Font.Handle);
  GetTextMetrics(DC, FixTM);
  SelectObject(DC, SaveFont);
 finally
  ReleaseDC(0, DC);
 end;

 if GetControlBaseLine(Control, CtrlTM, CtrlBL) and
  GetControlBaseLine(FixedControl, FixTM, FixBL) then
   Control.Top:= FixedControl.Top + (FixBL - CtrlBL);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered putting the labels above the edit boxes (or using TLabeledEdit instead)? Not only does that make aligning them easier, it also covers the case of translations (e.g. of label captions) that are much longer in some languages than they are in English.

Comment: A good idea, especially w.r.t different length translations. But this doesn't really answer the question. Perhaps you should have posted it as a comment instead.

Comment: In `TLabeledEdit`, the Label is just put besides the Edit, but no baseline alignment is done.

Comment: @Marus The point was not baseline alignment, but putting the label above the edit box, for the reasons mentioned.

Comment: I don't like the Label above... :)

Comment: I also prefer my labels to the left.